# The Windows 10 Start menu is not launching applications

Tags: windows, windows-10, start-menu

In Windows 10, if I open the StartMenu and then type an application name like *mspaint*, *slack*,  *skype*, etc., the application  *is* found but then clicking on the name does nothing -- it does not launch the application.

The failure started about a month ago. I do not know what conditioned it.

These applications *are* installed and I can launch them in other ways. For example, I can open the Start menu and choose an application from "most used" or from the alphabetical list and it does launch.

How can I launch an application from the Start Menu search?

[image]

Comment: Workaround: Since Windows version 10.0.15063, I have found that keyboard shortcuts to links no longer work. After some time trying to fix this issue from within Windows, I've found two applications that fix the issue: Classic Shell to replace the Start Menu, and Clavier+ to create keyboard shortcuts to applications. See http://www.classicshell.net/ and http://utilfr42.free.fr/util/Clavier.php?sLang=en .

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thank you! Classic Shell replaced the Start menu very nicely. If you can put this as an answer I can Accept it.

Comment: Done... these comments will be deleted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround: Since Windows version 10.0.15063, I have found that keyboard shortcuts to links no longer work. After some time trying to fix this issue from within Windows, I've found two applications that bypass the issue: [Classic Shell](http://classicshell.net) to replace the Start Menu, and [Clavier+](http://utilfr42.free.fr/util/Clavier.php?sLang=en) to create keyboard shortcuts to applications.

[image: Classic Shell Start Menu]

[image: Clavier+ Keyboard Shortcuts]

An additional benefit of these applications is that the configuration can be saved for use as backup and exported to customize another PC.

Comment: I used Classic Shell and configured it to replace the Start Menu (but no other components.) It does the job and also allows access to the built-in Start Menu with CTRL-click on the Start Menu icon.

Comment: Good... in my case, that worked for a while, then another Windows update broke the keyboard shortcuts, so keep Clavier+ or alternatives in mind should MS further "improve" Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Using “***sfc /scannow***” to check/repair system files.

Re-start system in Clean Boot, do not manually open process and try search function to open application. It will help you to determine whether it is relate to 3rd party process effect.

**How to perform a clean boot in Windows**:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows

Check/install available Windows Update.